# How do I remove 'plus' tags from email addresses in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, email-address

I have a table containing email addresses where some of them contain 'plus' tags - for example,

```
email
----------------------
user1@example.com
user2@example.org
user1+test@example.com
```

I need to be able to query the table and receive the email addresses without the tags:

```
email
----------------------
user1@example.com
user2@example.org
user1@example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query strips the tag from email addresses on all versions of MySQL:

```
SELECT IF(LOCATE('+', email) = 0, 
  email,
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(email, 1, LOCATE('+', email) - 1), 
    SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('@', email))))
FROM my_table;
```

In English: if there is no `+` in the email address, then just use the email address; otherwise, concatenate the text to the left of the `+` with the text from the `@` to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `regexp_replace()` for this:

```
select
    email,
    regexp_replace(email, '\\+[^@].*@+', '@') new_email
from mytable
```

This phrases as: suppress any sequence of characters starting with `'+'` until `'@'`. If there is no match, `regexp_replace()` leaves the string untouched.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5B5XXsjAuDSaZY9h5aBzuJ/1)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select 'user1@example.org' email
    union all select 'user2@example.org'
    union all select 'user1+test@example.com'
)
select
    email,
    regexp_replace(email, '\\+[^@].*@+', '@') new_email
from mytable;

| email                  | new_email         |
| ---------------------- | ----------------- |
| user1@example.org      | user1@example.org |
| user2@example.org      | user2@example.org |
| user1+test@example.com | user1@example.com |
```

Comment: That last row is incorrect - it should be `user1@example.com`

Comment: Thanks - nicer than my first try :-)

Comment: Welcome. But it requires MySQL 8.0 though, while your solution works on all versions of MySQL.